# how to create html template and use in JS

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a scenario like this , where html is used in JS and without using html in JS , how can I refer the html as template in my JS. I want to use it as template . Instead of building the html in javascript,i want do it in the template.

```
if (value === ' ') {
   $scope.error.push('<p>' + Code + '</p>');
} 
else {
  $scope.error.push('<p>' + value.code + '</p>');
}
```

Comment: See [AngularJS ng-bind-html  Directive API Reference - Example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml#examples)

Answer (score 0):

Put your HTML in

```
<script type="text/template">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p class="name">Nicoleta</p>
  </div>
</script>
```

And use DOMParser to extract it as a template. Eg.,

```
const html = new DOMParser().parseFromString(document.querySelector('[type="text/template"]').innerText, 'text/html')
```

What whatever you want with your `html`.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this may u get.

```
 <html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <p ng-bind-html="myText"></p>

    </div>

    <script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.myText = "My name is: <h1>John Doe</h1>";
    if (value === ' ') {
     $scope.error= "My name is: <h1>code</h1>";
    } 
    else {
    $scope.error= "My name is: <h1>error code</h1>";
    }
    });
    </script>

    <p><b>Note:</b> This example includes the "angular-sanitize.js",
    which has functions for removing potentially dangerous tokens from 
    the HTML.</p>

    </body>
    </html>
```